# Remote access elasticsearch 9200 fails

Tags: security, elasticsearch, cloud, ovh

I have a problem that i am facing but i didn't found solution in the forum and into elasticsearch official documentation. I have successfully installed elasticsearch 1.7.3 in OVH cloud machin and being able to connect via localhost  through the curl localhost:9200. But i tried to connect remotely using http://158.69.78.66:9200/  (where 158.69.78.66 is the server address) without success. Please which configuration am i going to more in order to be able to remotely access elasticSearch in my server.

The attached file represent my elasticsearch.yml actual configuration.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking port 9200 by any chance? Can you try to set `network.host: 158.69.78.66` in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration?

Comment: How are you accessing elasticsearch? If you're using a javascript application which accesses elasticsearch directly, then you have to take care of a proper CORS configuration.